# Changing Normal Faces

Tags: normals, transform-orientation

I would like to know if there is a way to change normals faces orientation of a figure. I followed a tutorial for making leaves in a tree but it finishes with unity i think.
here is a figure:

[image]

he uses a lager shape to steal normals from it like this:[image]

before:[image: before]
after:[image: after]
so he finally gets this result: [image]

I tried with data transfert modifier, normal edit modifier and edit mode/mesh/normals but i only manage to change split normals so i dont get the same effect. Maybe there is a way with the nodes or with a better use of modifiers or even deeper with scripting. Im a beginner so maybe someone could help me.

[image]